# Cordova - iOS8 Interactive Notification Widgets

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ios8

Is it possible to create and control the new Interactive Notifications within Cordova?

Trying to find documentation on this and reaching a blank. Any links appreciated.

I basically want to show a message that can be swiped with options to remove or action.

Many thanks